# Sort iframes without reloading in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, sorting, iframe

How to sort iFrames without reloading using Angular?

I've created a simple list with *ngFor="let v of videos"
and embed some youtube videos.

If I sort array of videos all iframes reloaded.

But I want to sort if from code without reloading like flexbox-reverse does.

Comment: Not having much context around this, could you tell me how you are sorting the videos array? Are you doing assignment like `this.videos = someSortMethod(videos)`

Comment: You are probably going to be limited to "sorting" them by using CSS, eg absolute/fixed positioning. As sorting them by actually moving them around in DOM will make them reload